# How to rewrite AJAX request from vanilla JS to JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ajax-request

Currently I'm studying JS and pretty familiar with the vanilla JS, but JQuery syntax seems a little bit weird for me. So I have the following code on JS and it works just fine:

```
let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    questions = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    loadQuestionsData();
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/questions", true);
xhttp.send();
```

Here I create new XMLHttpRequest to my localhost and get JSON of questions and when the responce is ready, the function *loadQuestionsData()* is executed (it inserts the list of questions into the table).
I've tried to rewrite this with JQuery, but it doesn't work and I do not get why. Here is my n-th try to do this:

```
$(document).on('readystatechange', function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/questions",
    type: 'GET',
    success: function() {
      questions = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      loadQuestionsData();
    }
  })
})
```

I've also tried the following, but it doesn't work too:

```
$(document).on('readystatechange', function() {
  questions = JSON.parse($.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/questions",
    type: 'GET',
  })).responseText;
})
```

I suppose the problem is with syntax? Code stops running on *responseText*.

Comment: Check the console for errors. I'd guess the issue is because jQuery will deserialise the response for you, hence you're calling `JSON.parse()` on an object and getting an error.

Comment: Does the document object have a `readystatechange` event?  Just move the code out of that event handler and it should work.

Comment: @Archer well spotted, missed that. OP, use a document.ready handler instead; `$(function() { $.ajax(...`

Comment: did you import the jquery lib?

Comment: @Archer,  thanks for the help! I've made these improvements but still my code stops when it gets to the JSON.parse(this.responseText). It returns undefined and I guess I should use something else to get the response Text from my request?

Comment: @JitendraMeena yes, I use it below and it works. However probably it is not allowed to write (this.responseText)? Cause it returns 'undefined'

Comment: I've added an answer to cover both issues I see with your code.  That should help you out :)

Comment: @Archer, yes, thank you for the help! Finally I can go forward with my project :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document object does not have an `onreadystatechange` event - that's part of the XHR object.  The jQuery AJAX methods will handle state changes for you (part of the simplicity of it).

Also, the success handler has a parameter that is the response text, so you need to add that to the function signature so you can access it in the function.

Change it to this instead...

```
  $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:8080/questions",
      type: 'GET',
          success: function(responseText) {
          questions = JSON.parse(responseText);
          loadQuestionsData();
      }
  })
```

Comment: WOW that helped me a lot! Now it works nice! Besides I've revealed that now I can remove JSON.parse because *responseText* is already parsed the way I needed! Thanks you a lot for the help!

Comment: No problem - glad it helped you out :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use :

```
$(document).on('readystatechange', function() {
});
```

as `readystatechange` is a property of XmlHttpRequest();

simply change your code to:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/questions",
    type: 'GET',
    success: function() {
      questions = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      loadQuestionsData();
    }
  });
```

Comment: Yes, I did it and it works just nice! Thank you for the help!